# Convert Unix-Style Path to Windows

Tags: bash, path, sh, cross-platform, git-bash

I have the same Bash script that I am running on Linux, Mac, and Windows (with Git Bash).

How can I make sure that the path is converted to a Windows-style path ONLY if running in Git Bash?

```sh
java -classpath "./path-1/subdir:./path-2" com.example.Main
```

Comment: I have never userd git-bash, but [reportedly](https://superuser.com/questions/1191805/can-git-bash-and-cygwin-shell-do-the-same-things), git-bash (like cygwin) contains the `cygpath` command. Can you verify this?

Comment: Yes, it does. But how do I use it when it will not be defined on Linux/Mac?

Comment: @JeremyEastham As seen in my script below: you use by default Unix path. Except if cygpath is detected.

Comment: In my project (using Cygpath), I have a general startup file for all my scripts. In this, I test the platform (using `uname`), and define a function named _localpath_: If I'm not on Cygwin, this function simply echoes the argument to stdout unmodified. Otherwise, the function invokes, say,  `cygpath -m` on the argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test for the presence of [`cygpath.exe`](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/cygpath.html):

```sh
classpath="./path-1/subdir:./path-2"

if which cygpath.exe > /dev/null; then
  classpath="$(cygpath.exe -C ANSI -w -p "${classpath}")"
fi

java -classpath "${classpath}" com.example.Main
```

But check first if you even need that conversion: in a bash shell script (even with Git For Windows bash), a Unix-style path will work when calling scripts/executables. However, strings passed as arguments are passed as-is.

Comment: Couldn't cygpath be installed onto a Linux machine?

Comment: @JeremyEastham If I added the right separator.

Comment: @JeremyEastham cypath yes, cypath.exe no: I have updated the script.